# Cannot get casperjs to run on Windows 7

Tags: python, node.js, windows, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using NodeJS and have downloaded the casperjs and phantomjs packages via npm.  I have downloaded Python 3.4 and added it to my path.  However, when I try to run casperjs I get the error

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have also tried downloading the packages from the respective websites of the packages, adding them to my path, etc. to no avail.  I am using Windows 7.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Close the cmd window and open it again. If this doesn't work, restart.

Comment: @ArtjomB. despite that not working the 10 other times I tried it, it worked then...  Any chance having it installed globally and locally would have anything to do with it?  I uninstalled locally and just had it run globally.

Comment: In Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 (versions I pointed out already), the `%PATH%` must be added manually to Python, Casperjs and PhantomJS. 
After that, my code always worked ...